# Change function when <submit> value changes

Tags: html

I am trying to make a simple calculator. So far, I have been able to do one algorithm (+ - x /) at a time. Now, I want to make a calculator that has a submit menu that can select what you want to do. My code is this:

```html
<input type="text" id="inputone">


<select>

<option>
  +
</option>

<option>
-
</option>

<option>
x
</option>

<option>
/
</option>

</select>

<input type="text" id="inputtwo">

<p> = </p>

<p id="answer"></p>

<script>
 //Some code...
</script>

<button onclick="ad()">Solve</button>
```

I have researched a bit and I haven't found a good way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been coding for under a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<option></option>` elements in HTML has an attribute called `value` that you can use in JavaScript in order to make a condition of what operation you need to do.

For example, if your user selects the `*` operation. In the `click` event you are adding to the button, you can get that value through the `DOM API` with its `.value` property:

```
function defineOperation() {
  var operation = document.getElementById('select-id').value;
  // conditions go here to decide what operation to execute
}
```

Comment: would `select-id` be the default id of the select? and do I add a `onclick="defineOperation()"` to the option boxes?

Comment: `select-id` would be the id of the `select`, the click `event` should be added to the `button`